# Manipulating Raspbery PI's DC motor speed while running GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, raspberry-pi3, gpio

*Raspberry Pi beginner*

I am programming GUI application(using **PyQt5**) for controlling DC motor.
So far I am able to control my motor via motor driver and change it's speed in terminal(using **PWM**).

The problem comes when I want my motor controller code in my GUI application, because when I run function for motor movement my time.sleep(x) stops the whole GUI application, so I can not make changes on motor's speed.

I found that threading would probably save my problem, but I don't know how to modify speed while thread is running.

Here is my code for running motor:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# set pins as output
GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)


p = GPIO.PWM(17,80)
p.start(40)
p.ChangeDutyCycle(50)

GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(4,GPIO.HIGH)
print("4 is HIGH")
time.sleep(5)
p.ChangeDutyCycle(70)#speed change

#change direction of motor spinning
GPIO.output(4,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
print("18 is HIGH")



p.stop()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Python for GUI:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,uic, QtCore

...

def start():
    while True:
        #run motor here


dlg.btn_start.clicked.connect(start)

...
```

I hope that I didn't make this more complicated than it already is,
thank you all for answers!

Best regards!

Comment: where is your GUI?

Comment: Added GUI code, I don't think that really matters, since I didn't even know how to start including threading with options to change speed inside thread.

Comment: that is not a GUI, they are pieces of code, I also think that it is not necessary since the task of changing the pwm is not blocking. and the GUI is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution:***

I made it work with Python multiprocessing.

My program is now separated in two processes:

**1.The GUI process**, which runs the GUI and signal which runs a function for speed change when slider is changed. And whenever slider's position is changed the value is saved into text file.

**2.Motor process** is process which is reading the same file all the time and applying value from file to motor speed. If that value is set to 0, motor is Off.

I assume this is not the only solution and of course not the best, but it works for me.

I hope that will help to some of you too!

Cheers!

And of course the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,uic, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox,QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer,QTime
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Value

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
dlg = uic.loadUi("Motor.ui")


def startMotor():
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            file = open("test.txt", "r") 
            a=file.read()
            file.close()
            if int(a) == 0:
                print("OFF")
                #motor is off
            else:
                #motor is ON
                print("ON, speed is:", a)
    except:
        print("Abort...")

def runProgram():
    dlg.show()
    app.exec()


def changeSpeed():
    dlg.label.setText(str(dlg.slider.value()))

    file = open("test.txt","w") 
    file.write(str(dlg.slider.value()))
    file.close() 

#when slider's value is changed
dlg.slider.valueChanged.connect(changeSpeed)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #On Program load    
    p1 = Process(target=startMotor,args=())
    p2 = Process(target=runProgram,args=())

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

If anyone is interested in learning the basics of PyQt5 design, check my YouTube channel where I explain the basics:
[Link](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMZVBPh0FfOJfAfQ47cg8xA?view_as=subscriber)